# Has anyone implemented the OSS ReportServer package to pull reports from an Asigra backup solution?

Tags: backup, reporting

We have Asigra set up by our service provider and we need a way to build better reports than those that are built-in. We have the Java DS-User package installed so, according to Asigra documentation, JasperReports is the option to go with. However, JasperReports Community version is limited in its abilities and paying out for the Enterprise version will be a hard sell.

I found that ReportServer provides some of the functionality that the JR Community version has crippled, but I don't know if it is able to connect to Asigra easily.

Has anyone put this to use or any other, similar package with Asigra?